# Apache not serving local hosts

Tags: php, php-fpm, apache2

I have set up an Apache Server on an a VMWare hosted Linux Mint 21 Server, I have followed the instructions at [this blog](https://bobcares.com/blog/run-multiple-php-versions-apache-php-fpm/) to run multiple PHP versions (7.4 and 8.1).

Apache is running fine and serving pages on localhost ok but the Virtual Servers just time out with "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".  I'm stumped as to what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the config file for the PHP 7 version:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin legacy@mydomain.org.uk
ServerName legacy.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/legacy.local
DirectoryIndex info.php

<Directory /var/www/legacy.local>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
# From the Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use the SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/legacy.local_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/legacy.local_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the config file for the PHP 8 version:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin new@mydomain.org.uk
ServerName new.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/new.local
DirectoryIndex info.php

<Directory /var/www/new.local>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
# From the Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use the SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/new.local_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/new.local_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The error logs show FPM for PHP7 available:-

```
[08-Dec-2022 13:20:36] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 801
[08-Dec-2022 13:20:36] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Dec-2022 13:20:36] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

The error logs show FPM for PHP8 available as well:-

```
[08-Dec-2022 13:20:36] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 821
[08-Dec-2022 13:20:36] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Dec-2022 13:20:36] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

Comment: At first glance, the use of `.local` hostname *might* be an issue and causing your `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`  DNS error . - The [`.local TLD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) is a special use domain reserved for [multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) and not supposed to be used (anymore)  for your internal domain.

Comment: Thanks, changed that but it made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: You are getting a DNS error, so you need to look into your DNS configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this configuration working, I reset the VM and used the [instructions here](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu/) to set up the two versions of PHP.

To sum up:-

```
#Set up default Web Server with PHP 8.x
sudo apt-get install -y lamp-server^
#Add PHP 7.x
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y php7.4
```

To switch from PHP 8.x to 7.x:-

```
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl status apache2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

To switch from PHP 7.x to 8.x:-

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl status apache2
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl status apache2
```